Filter and compare on grouped rows (tidyverse)
I have a dataframe and I want to find the duplicates, and either choose one row or keep more than one, depending on a column condition.
tst <- data.frame(dataset=as.factor(c(rep("DS1", 4), rep("DS2", 3), rep("DS3", 3))), 
           gene1=c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA"),
           gene2=c("BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB" ),
           confidence=c("high", "low", "medium", "high", "low", "low", "medium", "low", "high", "high"),
           dist_g1=c(1, 1, 3, 1, 0,0,0,6,6,0),
           dist_g2=c(0, 0, 0, 2, 0,0,0,4,4,12) )





dataset
gene1
gene2
confidence
dist_g1
dist_g2




1
DS1
AAA
BBB
high
1
0


2
DS1
AAA
BBB
low
1
0


3
DS1
AAA
BBB
medium
3
0


4
DS1
AAA
BBB
high
1
2


5
DS2
AAA
BBB
low
0
0


6
DS2
AAA
BBB
low
0
0


7
DS2
AAA
BBB
medium
0
0


8
DS3
AAA
BBB
low
6
4


9
DS3
AAA
BBB
high
6
4


10
DS3
AAA
BBB
high
0
12



I need to modify the duplicated rows (grouping on "dataset", "gene1", "gene2"), as follows:

if in a group, each of the distances is the same, (e.g. rows (1 & 2), (5, 6 & 7), (8 & 9)) but "confidence" is different, keep the row with highest level of confidence (high > medium > low) -> keep rows 1, 7, 9

if the distances in the grouping are different, keep all different rows in that group (e.g. rows (1, 3, 4), (5), (9, 10))


The final dataframe would look like this:
(please ignore the index column, it is there just to explain better)



---
dataset
gene1
gene2
confidence
dist_g1
dist_g2




1
DS1
AAA
BBB
high
1
0


3
DS1
AAA
BBB
medium
3
0


4
DS1
AAA
BBB
high
1
2


7
DS2
AAA
BBB
medium
0
0


9
DS3
AAA
BBB
high
6
4


10
DS3
AAA
BBB
high
0
12



What I have tried:

for the first point, I group and filter by 'confidence'

tst %>% 
  mutate(confidence = factor(confidence, levels = c("low", "medium", "high"), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(dataset, gene1, gene2) %>% 
  top_n(n=1, confidence)


I tried to include an "if statement" or a "case_when", but I don't know how to compare adjacent rows

Thank you for your help!

Here is my answer
(tst 
  %>% 
  mutate(
      confidence_fact = factor(
        confidence, 
        levels = c("low", "medium", "high"), 
        ordered = TRUE
      )
  ) 
  %>% group_by(dataset, gene1, gene2,dist_g1,dist_g2) 
  %>% mutate(
    order_conf=case_when(
      confidence == 'low'    ~ 1L,
      confidence == 'medium' ~ 2L,
      confidence == 'high'   ~ 3L,
      .default = 1L
    ),
    max_order_conf=max(order_conf)
  )
  %>% filter(order_conf==max_order_conf)
  %>% select (-max_order_conf,-order_conf)
)


#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   dataset, gene1, gene2, dist_g1, dist_g2 [6]
#>   dataset gene1 gene2 confidence dist_g1 dist_g2
#>   <fct>   <chr> <chr> <ord>        <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 DS1     AAA   BBB   high             1       0
#> 2 DS1     AAA   BBB   medium           3       0
#> 3 DS1     AAA   BBB   high             1       2
#> 4 DS2     AAA   BBB   medium           0       0
#> 5 DS3     AAA   BBB   high             6       4
#> 6 DS3     AAA   BBB   high             0      12

With factor case_when() is unnecessary
(tst 
  %>% 
    mutate(      
      confidence_fact = factor(
        confidence, 
        levels = c("low", "medium", "high"), 
        ordered = TRUE
      )
    ) 
  %>% group_by(dataset, gene1, gene2,dist_g1,dist_g2) 
  %>% mutate(
    max_conf_factor=max(confidence_fact)
  )
  %>% filter(confidence_fact==max_conf_factor)
  %>% select (-max_conf_factor,-confidence_fact)
)


#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   dataset, gene1, gene2, dist_g1, dist_g2 [6]
#>   dataset gene1 gene2 confidence dist_g1 dist_g2
#>   <fct>   <chr> <chr> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 DS1     AAA   BBB   high             1       0
#> 2 DS1     AAA   BBB   medium           3       0
#> 3 DS1     AAA   BBB   high             1       2
#> 4 DS2     AAA   BBB   medium           0       0
#> 5 DS3     AAA   BBB   high             6       4
#> 6 DS3     AAA   BBB   high             0      12


Thank you for your help, this gives me exactly what I need in the big dataset I have!

I have clicked on the button, but I don't have enough reputation yet to cast my vote. But I am on the way! :D Again, thank you for your help!

Ok  I understand :D
